# How to add HTML/CSS using the editor on DNN? How to add markup without relying on modules?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I don't have direct Host or Superuser access to DNN and the way our system is set up I wont get access to those accounts. It is a policy where i work. Is there ANY way to get your HMTL/CSS to actually work as you put it into the DNN HMTL editor?  I have tried adding things like an accordion sidebar, tabbed area, and a simple CSS image hover.  DNN takes my code and jumbles it up so that it does not work correctly.  I have taken markup straight from my text editor, into dnn (that was working fine in the browsers before i took it into DNN) and it shows up, but does not act like it should or the code gets jumbled and breaks and I spend an hour trying to fix it EVERY TIME.

Has anyone out there had the same issue, or any suggestions, tricks to get your markup to work correctly in DNN.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, you can't add scripts in the html editor and if you are copy-pasting something that has a FORM element, it won't directly work without modification.

One possible way to keep your javascript working is to move it to the Header or Footer options in the module options of that module instead of the content.

As for if your code contains a FORM element, you can use javascript to modify the Asp.NET FORM element to suit your need, see http://dotnetnuke.bz/Articles/tabid/156/DotNetNuke/98/How-to-Include-Multiple-Forms-in-DotNetNuke.aspx for more details.

Comment: and what about adding just HTML5 and CSS3?  That is where i am having the problems, the HTML editor jumbles my code when it works fine outside of DNN before i bring it into HTML Pro module, for this CMS being "open source," its not very open source if you ask me.

Comment: If you don't want the HTML module to modify your code and prefer to make it outside of DotNetNuke, then you can click the "Basic TextBox" option just above the HTML editor and paste your html source there. You have less chances of the visual editor messing around with your code.

Comment: I didn't even think to use that Basic TextBox option, that makes a ton of sense, thanks!